# how to prevent on click to work infinite times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling

once i click these buttons the function provided to them by onClick event does an infinite loop and the page freezes

is there any possible way to prevent it?

```
<section>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ category: "image" });
            }}
          >
            Image
          </button>
          <Button>Figure</Button>
          <Button>Image</Button>
        </section>
        <section className="hello">
          {this.state.store &&
            this.state.store.map((st) => {
              if (st[0].exist && st[0].category == this.state.category) {
                return (
                  <div className="eachC">
                    <Card
                      category={st[0].category}
                      image={st[0].image}
                      price={st[0].price}
                      name={st[0].name}
                    />
                    <section>
                      <Button onClick={this.setState({ save: 1 }, () => {})}>
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                      <Button onClick={this.setState({ save: 1 }, () => {})}>
                        Update
                      </Button>
                    </section>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
        </section>
```

Comment: Do you have any componentDidUpdate?

Comment: no i dont i have another project that works well with onClick tried to mimic the method on that project but still didnt work

Comment: We need more code to see what is happening, with only the buttons is really hard to check it :(

Comment: The only thing that I can tell you is that the first button is different from the others `button` `Button`

Comment: thats the entire render after edit seems right to me

Comment: the setState inside the 2 onClick event have to be in a function because here you call the setSate on each render. so you enter in an infinie loop.
`onClick={() => this.setState({ save: 1 }, () => {})}`

Comment: ohhh right thank you i didnt even think about this part being the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to tell exactly why an infinite loop is caused without seeing what other logic you have prior to the render, and also without knowing which buttons are causing you the issue, because you currently have multiple buttons that do different things.

However I can see right now that you are not passing a function to the `onClick` event for the Update and Delete button, but instead you are making a function call, which will be called when the component is rendered instead of when clicking. So it is bound to not work properly.

You need to wrap those in a function like you do for your Image button, and you also don't need the empty callback you have added. So I would change that to something like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.setState({ save: 1 })}>
    Delete
</Button>
<Button onClick={() => this.setState({ save: 1 })}>
    Update
</Button>
```

However, I am not sure if this is what is causing your infinite loop as you haven't included any more logic in your question!